# Running systemml codes on windows system

Tags: systemml

I am trying out the basic systemML tutorial on my windows machine. However since the instructions are for OS X and linux I am facing some issues in implementing

For example while working with the Habeman data Set which I have downloaded and kept in a folder data as haberman.data as described [here](http://apache.github.io/incubator-systemml/standalone-guide) i am getting this error

```
C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra>cd C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\systemml-0.13.0-incubating-bin

C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\systemml-0.13.0-incubating-bin>echo '{"rows": 306, "cols": 4, "format": "csv"}' > data/haberman.data.mtd

C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\systemml-0.13.0-incubating-bin>echo '1,1,1,2' > data/types.csv

C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\systemml-0.13.0-incubating-bin>echo '{"rows": 1, "cols": 4, "format": "csv"}' > data/types.csv.mtd

C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\systemml-0.13.0-incubating-bin>./runStandaloneSystemML.sh scripts/algorithms/Univar-Stats.dml -nvargs X=data/haberman.data TYPES=data/types.csv STATS=data/univarOut.mtx CONSOLE_OUTPUT=TRUE
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\rajarshi.bhadra\Desktop\systemml-0.13.0-incubating-bin>runStandaloneSystemML scripts/algorithms/Univar-Stats.dml -nvargs X=data/haberman.data TYPES=data/types.csv STATS=data/univarOut.mtx CONSOLE_OUTPUT=TRUE
17/03/13 13:33:52 INFO api.DMLScript: BEGIN DML run 03/13/2017 13:33:52
17/03/13 13:33:53 ERROR api.DMLScript: Failed to execute DML script.
org.apache.sysml.parser.LanguageException: ERROR: scripts/algorithms/Univar-Stats.dml -- line 45, column 0 -- error parsing MTD file with path data/haberman.data.mtd: Error parsing json
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.Expression.raiseValidateError(Expression.java:551)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.Expression.raiseValidateError(Expression.java:521)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DataExpression.readMetadataFile(DataExpression.java:2006)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DataExpression.checkHasMatrixMarketFormat(DataExpression.java:2071)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DataExpression.validateExpression(DataExpression.java:652)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.StatementBlock.validate(StatementBlock.java:567)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DMLTranslator.validateParseTree(DMLTranslator.java:140)
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.execute(DMLScript.java:586)
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.executeScript(DMLScript.java:346)
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.main(DMLScript.java:207)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.sysml.api.DMLException: org.apache.sysml.parser.LanguageException: ERROR: scripts/algorithms/Univar-Stats.dml -- line 45, column 0 -- error parsing MTD file with path data/haberman.data.mtd: Error parsing json
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.executeScript(DMLScript.java:360)
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.main(DMLScript.java:207)
Caused by: org.apache.sysml.parser.LanguageException: ERROR: scripts/algorithms/Univar-Stats.dml -- line 45, column 0 -- error parsing MTD file with path data/haberman.data.mtd: Error parsing json
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.Expression.raiseValidateError(Expression.java:551)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.Expression.raiseValidateError(Expression.java:521)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DataExpression.readMetadataFile(DataExpression.java:2006)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DataExpression.checkHasMatrixMarketFormat(DataExpression.java:2071)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DataExpression.validateExpression(DataExpression.java:652)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.StatementBlock.validate(StatementBlock.java:567)
        at org.apache.sysml.parser.DMLTranslator.validateParseTree(DMLTranslator.java:140)
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.execute(DMLScript.java:586)
        at org.apache.sysml.api.DMLScript.executeScript(DMLScript.java:346)
        ... 1 more
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is likely just a missing newline at the end of your data/haberman.data.mtd file (as it currently fails while parsing this json file).

If this does not help, here is a workaround: As SystemML does not necessarily need the mtd file for csv input data, you could also remove the mtd file and put a format="csv" in the read statement of Univar-Stats.dml.